# Cancellation of Direct Product in Top

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm thinking to the famous problem of cancellation property in Top, i.e: $$T_1 \times T_2 \cong T_1 \times T_3 \Rightarrow T_2 \cong T_3. $$
Clearly there are many counterexamples like $\prod_{i \in \omega}S_{1_{i}}$ or $ \oplus_{i \in \omega}S_{1_{i}}$ but these counterexamples can be bypassed by giving a definition.

We say that a topological space T is $\Pi$-compact iff $$T \cong \prod_{i\in I}T_i, \  T_i \neq \{e\} \ \Rightarrow |I| < \infty.$$

We say that a topological space T is $\Sigma$-compact iff $$T \cong \oplus_{i\in I}T_i, \  T_i \neq \{e\} \ \Rightarrow |I| < \infty.$$

**We say that a topological space is $\times$-compact iff it's $\Pi$ and $\Sigma$ compact.**

Actually an easy conjecture is the following.

$$ \ \ \ \ \ T \times\text{-compact} \Rightarrow \text{cancellation property holds}.$$

But I do believe that's **false** and my plan to prove it is the following:
a pair of weeks ago I've posted question about [$\times$-compact groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042904/cancellation-of-direct-product-in-grp) and counterexample is [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=61&t=351637) so if I find a $\times$-compact topological space $\bar{T}$ such that $\pi_1(\bar{T})=$ counterexample I think I'm done.

I'm thinking at this right in these days so probably I'll answer to myselfsoon.
I'll note here my doubt and claims.

Comment: This could answer your question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384288/if-s-times-mathbbr-is-homeomorphic-to-t-times-mathbbr-and-s-and-t-a

Comment: I'm not sure it does.

Comment: Gasp! U're right, I got blind.

Answer (score 0):

R. H. Fox, On a problem of S. Ulam concerning Cartesian products, Fund. Math. 34 (1947) 278-287, constructed nonhomeomorphic compact $4$-dimensional manifolds $A$ and $B$ with $A\times A$ homeomorphic to $B\times B$; it follows that $(A+B)\times A$ is homeomorphic to $(A+B)\times B$.

Comment: Is the argument a $\pi_1$-argument or they use other ideas?

Comment: Your first link to the Scottish book seems to be broken.